# Delete all rows except

Tags: mysql, syntax, sql-delete

When I execute this query:

```
DELETE FROM `wp_posts` WHERE id NOT IN 
  (SELECT id FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish')
```

I get the following error message:

> You can't specify target table 'wp_posts' for update in FROM clause

Not sure what the syntax issue is here.

Comment: The problem is that you can't have the same table in a subquery during a `DELETE`. The way the queries are handled would cause undefined behaviour if it were allowed.

Comment: gee, i wish the error message would say it that clearly...error messages for dummies?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This can be done without using a sub-query. Please try the following

```
DELETE FROM 'wp_posts' WHERE post_status != 'publish'
```

Comment: ahh, yes, i tried that approach but got the != syntax wrong...thanks!